# Not receive email even after defining email in user profile

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created an alert on task list but I did not get email even after defining valid email in user profile according to below pictures.

Please help what is the problem

[image: error]

[image: user profile email]

Answer (score 1):

You need to Configure outgoing email for your SharePoint Server farm. To eable outgoing email, you have install and configure the SMTP service.

Please refer to this article for more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/outgoing-email-configuration